# Python: A curve between 2 lines with linearly varying first derivative

Tags: python, derivative

Imagine I have 2 points A,B in a 2D plane, and I know the derivative of the curve at point A and point B.
I would like to build a curve with a pre-specified number of points such that the first derivative of the line drawn by the new points changes linearly.

[image]

Comment: If the first derivative changes linearly, then the second is constant. So you're fitting a quadratic! Problem is, a quadratic has three unknowns and you've got four constraints - two known derivatives and two known points. This means it won't be solvable generally.

Comment: the constraints can be greater than the unknowns isnt it ?

Comment: More constraints than unknowns means no solution, unless your constraints align in a nice way. See 'overdetermined systems'.